# Send message to a Python Script

Tags: python, linux, bash, raspberry-pi, daemon

I'm trying to write a little python program for shutdown or Reboot my Raspberry PI, drived by a button connected to an GPIO. The program can show the current status of the raspberry PI (Booting,Running,Halting,Rebooting) via two leds.
The python program is executed as daemon, started by a init.d bash script (written using the /etc/init.d/skeleton).

Now I can start/stop/verify the status of the daemon, and the daemon can check the input where the button is connected, to perform the command  "shutdown -h now" or "shutdown -r now" .

For show the current status of the raspberry PI, I had thought of send messages to the daemon, using some script in the runlevels directorys, for change the status of the leds.
But I don't know how receive message in the python program.

Someone can help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are several methods to send a message from one script/app to another:

For you application a valid method is to use a named pipe. Create it using [os.mkfifo](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html), open it read-only in your python app and then wait for messages on it.

If you want your app to do another things while waiting, I reccomend you open the pipe in non-blocking mode to look for data availability without blocking your script as in following example:

```
import os, time

pipe_path = "/tmp/mypipe"
if not os.path.exists(pipe_path):
    os.mkfifo(pipe_path)
# Open the fifo. We need to open in non-blocking mode or it will stalls until
# someone opens it for writting
pipe_fd = os.open(pipe_path, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
with os.fdopen(pipe_fd) as pipe:
    while True:
        message = pipe.read()
        if message:
            print("Received: '%s'" % message)
        print("Doing other stuff")
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Then you can send messages from bash scripts using the command

`echo "your message" > /tmp/mypipe`

**EDIT:** I can not get select.select working correctly (I used it only in C programs) so I changed my recommendation to a non-bloking mode.

Comment: I don't understand the use of `select.select()` function in case of checking a file.
Can you help me with a exemple?
I need to wait for messages in a infinite loop.

Comment: I can not get select.select working correctly (I used it only in C programs) so I changed my recommendation to a non-bloking mode and added an example.

Comment: hello, when I try to run the command ´echo "your message" > /tmp/mypipe´ on the console I get a permission denied error. I already tried executing with sudo but same thing happens

Answer (score 1):

Is not more convenient this version? 
With the `with` costruct inside the `while true:` loop?
In this way, all other code inside the loop is executable even in case of error in the pipe file management. Eventually I can use the `try:` costuct
 for catching the error.

```
import os, time

pipe_path = "/tmp/mypipe"
if not os.path.exists(pipe_path):
    os.mkfifo(pipe_path)
# Open the fifo. We need to open in non-blocking mode or it will stalls until
# someone opens it for writting
pipe_fd = os.open(pipe_path, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK)

while True:
    with os.fdopen(pipe_fd) as pipe:
        message = pipe.read()
        if message:
            print("Received: '%s'" % message)

    print("Doing other stuff")
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: It is not safe to fdopen multiple times a pipe/file opened with os.open. When the "with" statement goes out of scope (The print("Doing other stuff") sentence) it closes the file descriptor and it can not be re-fdopened. Also it you close the pipe while another process is connected, that process will recieve the SIGPIPE signal and most probably terminate its execution. You should maintain the pipe open all the time you are in the loop.