# Import Python library in terminal

Tags: python

I need to run a **Python script** in a terminal, several times. This script requires me to import some libraries. So every time I call the script in the terminal, the libraries are loaded again, which results in a loss of time. Is there any way I can import the libraries once and for all at the beginning?
(If I try the "naive" way, calling first a script just to import libraries then running my code, it doesn't work).

EDIT: I need to run the script in a terminal because actually it is made to serve in another program developed in Java. The Java code calls the Pythin script in the terminal, reads its result and processes it, then calls it again.

Comment: How do you propose the *terminal* to remember what another program has called in memory? The only way (that I can think of) would be to run all your scripts within the same instance of Python interpreter.

Comment: Well I'm still a beginner so I might indeed be speaking nonsense. Can this be done while staying in the terminal?

Comment: To the best of my understanding, no, it's not possible unless you somehow have a master script.py managing all your child scripts within the same Python session.  And even then you'll need to do some clever work around in your child scripts so that it will use the master script's imported libraries instead of importing their own (which means it'll be difficult to do unit tests without a master script).  In short, the libraries loaded *in Python* have no relation to the *terminal*, so it knows not how to retain or retrieve these libraries for later use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is that you can leave the python script always running and use a pipe to communicate between processes like the code below taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813210/send-message-to-a-python-script) answer.

```
import os, time

pipe_path = "/tmp/mypipe"
if not os.path.exists(pipe_path):
    os.mkfifo(pipe_path)
# Open the fifo. We need to open in non-blocking mode or it will stalls until
# someone opens it for writting
pipe_fd = os.open(pipe_path, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
with os.fdopen(pipe_fd) as pipe:
    while True:
        message = pipe.read()
        if message:
            print("Received: '%s'" % message)
        print("Doing other stuff")
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Does not look easy to handle for a newbie like me but I will definitely give it a try. Thanks

Comment: Good luck with your projects! If anything just create other questions

Answer (score 1):

The libraries will be unloaded once the script finishes, so the best way you can handle this is to write the script so it can iterate however many times you want, rather than running the whole script multiple times. I would likely use input() (or raw_input() if you're running Python2) to read in however many times you want to iterate over it, or use a library like click to create a command line argument for it.