# Auto rerun of python scripts

Tags: python, powershell, automation

seeking everyone's help on my workplace python processes

Context:
-I have some python scripts running 24/7 in Powershell to process files that it detects in my folder), and then store them in the database (MySQL).
-However sometimes the script would hang (eg. due to a new error encountered, work server crash, etc).
-It caused some downtime as only my maintenance team can reset the script and they are not always around.

Trying to do:
-Whenever it detects that the script hangs, it will auto restart the scripts.

Apologies that I do not have sample scripts as all of them are stored in my workplace. I would appreciate it if you can share with me the rough thought process or examples (on other sites) so I can 'take off' on my own. thank you :)

Comment: What you can do is have a Watchdog script that if doesn't receive a message from the main script every X seconds kills and restarts it.  You can check how to send messages between scripts here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813210/send-message-to-a-python-script  And how to kill process here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278847/is-it-possible-to-kill-a-process-on-windows-from-within-python With this you can already start building the Watchdog.

Comment: Hi Sembei Norimaki, thanks for your input! i will go and experiment it

Answer (score 0):

The following bash script might help you:

```
#!/bin/bash

scripts=('python3 script1.py' 'python3 script2.py' 'python3 script3.py')

# loop through each python script you want and execute
for s in "${scripts[@]}"; do
    eval $s # run the script

    # pick up the exit code in variabl
    python_exit_status=$? 
    if [ "${python_exit_status}" -ne 0 ];
    then
        echo "Exit code not equal 0. Python script errored ... "
        # here, you want to reset from the beginning. Break and rerun entire bash script?
    else
        echo "Exit code 0. Continue as normal ... "
        # here, do nothing and allow it to continue.
    fi
done
```

The concept is that you loop through each of your python scripts, pick up on the exit code of said script, and then have a region where the bash code goes when the exit code is not equal to zero (i.e. Python script error/hangup occurs). Not sure what you want to do there though so I did not add any more. Did you want to restart from `script1` again if `script2` hangs up?

Comment: Hi Steinn Hauser, hmm the scripts all work independently. thanks for the help! i will go and experiment this

Comment: No worries! Let me know if there's any details of the implementation which I missed :)